# I got an error in Perl Missing comma after first argument to open function

Tags: database, perl, text

I am trying to make a database perl program . But i get this errors :

```
Missing comma after first argument to open function at database-txt.pl line 15, near "">$name.pswrd";"
Missing comma after first argument to open function at database-txt.pl line 25, near ""$a.nme";"
Missing comma after first argument to open function at database-txt.pl line 30, near ""$a.pswrd";"
```

Thanks!

```
sub change {
    my($a) = @_;
    chdir "$a" or die "ERROR: $!";
}
print "Do you want to register or log-in? "; chomp($a=<STDIN>);
if($a =~ /register/i) {
      print "What is your name: "; chomp($name=<STDIN>);
      print "What is your password: "; chomp($password=<STDIN>);
      change "name";
      open NAME, ">$name.nme";
      print NAME "$name";
      close NAME;
      change "..";
      change "password";
      open PASSWORD ">$name.pswrd";
      print PASSWORD "$password";
      close PASSWORD;
      change "..";
      print "Complete.\n";
}
else {
      print "Name: "; chomp($a=<STDIN>);
      print "Password: "; chomp($b=<STDIN>);
      change "name";
      open NAME "$a.nme";
      $c=<NAME>;
      close NAME;
      change "..";
      change "password";
      open PASSWORD "$a.pswrd";
      $d=<PASSWORD>;
      PASSWORD;
      "..";
}
if($a =~ /$c/ and $b =~ /$d/) {
      print "Log-in successful!\n";
      sleep(2);
      print  "Hello, $a!\n";
}
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory!

Comment: It might be, that you have a hidden fail in usuage. Sometimes the things are much more simple. Are you owner of file? Will it created? What results from giving a absolute or relative path like / or ./ ?

Comment: you are missing a comma after `PASSWORD` in this statement: `open PASSWORD ">$name.pswrd";`. See [`perldoc open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open NAME "$a.nme";
```

should be

```
open NAME, "$a.nme";
```

As an aside, I strongly recommend that you have your code [reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are numerous improvements that can be made.

Answer (score -3):

You forgot the ( )

open ( NAME, ">$name.pswrd" );

close ( NAME );

Comment: I also have in error at line 30 open(my $pswrd , $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; and that is Could not open file '' No such file or directory at database-txt.pl line 30. Can you help me with it please . I am new to perl

Comment: OP forgot a comma. (And it's poor practice to use bareword file handles and the two argument form of `open`).

Comment: No. The parenthesis are not required.